# Configure SQL to Import Excel Files with Specific Datetime Format

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2014, datetime-format

I have a few excel files (exported from very old SQL Server 6.5 database) that have datetime fields in this format:

```
DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

I wish to import these excel files into SQL Server 2014.
But, SQL Server 2014 accepts excel files with datetime format of:

```
YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS.FFF
```

My excel files couldn't be imported. Currently, I'm doing the formatting manually through excel formulas, which is a very tedious process.

Is there a way to configure SQL Server 2014 to take in excel files with a specific datetime format?

Comment: How did you try to load the data? Excel date fields have no data format. Dates are stored as OA Dates, ie decimals. What you see is the cell's display format. The data doesn't change. SQL Server has no trouble reading such dates through OLEDB, SSIS

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the import wizard through tasks?

I have managed to import the described data format from excel files. 
[image: Sample Excel data]

Via the Import wizard, once you get to the Source and detestation tab (Column Mappings), click edit mappings, make sure all your date fields from your excel SpreadSheet are set to type > "DateTime".
[image: Column Mappings tab]

SQL then should import them correctly and then convert them into the `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS.FFF` format.

Comment: Excel Dates are actually OADate decimals that OLEDB and SQL Server already understand. That's why the Import wizard works without modifications